# Sound Buttons don't play sound

Tags: c#, button, audio, input, xna

I'm making a program where one clicks buttons to create sound, like those instant button apps. But when I click the button, it won't play any sound. I don't know why either.
All my "Build" debugs are succeeding too.

These are my classes:

Game1.cs:

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Texture2D Background;
    Button button;



    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        this.Window.Title = "Bengt Slår På Knappar";
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 720;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1280;
        IsMouseVisible = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
    /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
    /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
    /// and initialize them as well.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

        base.Initialize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        Background = Content.Load<Texture2D>("bengtbakgrund");
        Texture2D Btexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Button");
        SoundEffect dundundun = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("DUN DUN DUN");
        button = new Button(dundundun, Btexture);

        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);


    }

    /// <summary>
    /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
    /// all content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
    /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();
        Rectangle mouseRect = new Rectangle(Mouse.GetState().X, Mouse.GetState().Y, 10, 10);
        MouseState mouseState = Mouse.GetState();


        if (mouseRect.Intersects(button.rect) && mouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            button.MySound.Play();
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }


    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(Background, new Vector2(0,0), Color.White);
        button.Draw(spriteBatch, new Vector2(300, 300));
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Button.cs:

```
public class Button
{

    Texture2D Texture { get; set; }
    public SoundEffect MySound { get; set; }
    public Rectangle rect;


    public Button(SoundEffect mySound, Texture2D texture)
    {
        MySound = mySound;
        Texture = texture;
    }

    public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
    {

    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {

    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Vector2 location)
    {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle((int)0, (int)0, Texture.Width, Texture.Height);

        spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, location, Color.White);
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is have one base button class, so if you want to add a new button with a sound, you just write: `button = new Button(//sound effect, //texture);`

But I can't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you put a breakpoint on the line that plays sound to see what happens?

Comment: Nevermind that, Looks like I found the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are handling your buttons position is incorrect, and I am not sure how it compiles. In your draw method you define a local variable `rect` that already exists. And even if it did, you are not taking into account the actual position of the button.

I think you could also move your button update logic into the class, so I will propose what I think you need to do.

public class Button
{
    //Properties
    private Texture2D Texture { get; set; }
    private SoundEffect Sound { get; set; }
    private Rectangle Rectangle { get; set; }

```
public Button(SoundEffect sound, Texture2D texture, Rectangle position)
{
    Sound = sound;
    Texture = texture;
    Rectangle = position;
}

public void Update(GameTime gameTime, MouseState mouseState)
{
      //If mouse is down and the rectangle contains the mouse point (Better for points than Intersect())
      if (mouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && Rectangle.Contains(new Point(mouseState.X,mouseState.Y))
      {
           Sound.Play()
      }
}

public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, rectangle, Color.White);
}
```

}

You can then just do `button.Update(Mouse.GetState())` (Or use another MouseState if you have one already)

It appears there was some confusion with the drawing position, vs the actual position of the button (in the draw method)

You need to make sure the button is aware of its position on the screen, as well as it's width and height.

```
button = new Button(dundundun, Btexture, new Rectangle(300, 300, Btexture.Width, Btexture.Height);
```

That will make the button at `300,500` and be the default size for the texture, now your sound button is *done done done* :)

I would also recommend learning and using [event handlers](http://www.dotnetperls.com/event), so you can add events for the button such as `button.Click += //Do something` easily

Comment: Haha, great, my sound button IS actually _done done done_ xDD
Thanks :3